# Fetching assests from cloud into Android app

Tags: android, resources, cloud, assets

I have an android app where I want to store images and lottie files in cloud, fetch them into local storage, and then render them from local storage and thus effectively reducing the app download size.

Comment: what you have done? Provide enough code! pls read this   https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Elango hi I have not done anything. I am asking just as a POC item. Since I am not able to find how to implement it